# Using library project doubles size of project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, library-project

I am developing an android app which is available as a free trial version and as a paid pro version. Of course, both are sharing large amounts of code so I moved the core functionality into an android library project. I created two independend android projects which use the core project as a library. So far, it works. But when compiling the final apps I realize the apps size more than doubled compared to the library project.

As I changed almost nothing besides the code layout I can't explain why this happens. I suppose it may have something to do with exported libraries the core library project includes.  In Eclipse I can see both the library project as well as the app projects do show all the jar files the library includes in their respective "Android Private Libraries"-folders. Are those libs included twice, maybe?

Comment: you can always view the files inside your apk... just rename it to myCoolApp.apk.zip and open it up. You could extract it and search for all files and sort them by file size and check it out. Also you should mention the file size. if it was 1mb then you exported it to a apk and it was 2mb then that is reasonable. If it was 20mb and it went to 40mb well then it might be another story.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was proguard that is (of course) not being invoked when building the library project. And the new app projects didn't have any proguard configuration yet. Adding proguard optimization to the app projects solved the issue. The complete build is now only 200KB bigger than before (1MB). Looks like this is the minimum overhead.